# Can battery inverters output reactive power?

Tags: batteries, inverter, reactive-power

This inverter manufacturer's Paper [*Bad Power Factor? – A reason to oversize your inverter*](https://www.sma-sunny.com/en/bad-power-factor-a-reason-to-oversize-your-inverter/) mentions that "inverters can generate reactive power without using any active power."

Can battery inverters also generate reactive power?

Can battery inverters absorb (?) reactive power when charging the battery?

Comment: Can you link to those papers?

Comment: A charger can have a PFC circuit (and with a certain wattage are required to have one) - are you asking about further improvements on this using the battery specifically?

Comment: @Jeroen3, here is the link to what i have read https://www.iotaengineering.com/pplib/IOTA_Tech_PFC%20in%20Battery%20Chargers.pdf

Comment: @Aresnal, i am asking whether the PFC can correct the power factor both while discharging and charging. I hope i am asking the correct question

Comment: I'm not quite sure what the definition of "power factor" when discharging a battery is, exactly? at which point do you measure that?

Comment: The phrase "discharge reactive power" does not appear in the linked article. If you are going to make a quote, make it verbatim or post a screen shot with the text highlighted. The word "discharge" appears twice and is related to "depth of discharge". You need to do better.

Comment: @Andy aka. The reason i say this is that i believe string inverters from a pv panel can "generate reactive power"  (https://www.sma-sunny.com/en/bad-power-factor-a-reason-to-oversize-your-inverter/) when the solar panels are producing and was wondering if battery inverters can do the same when the battery is being discharged. On the other hand i was wondering if battery inverters could also absorb (?) reactive power when charging the battery?

Comment: I don't think you got what I said - don't make half baked quotes - either verbatim or copy and paste - what you are saying doesn't tally with the paper you linked and leads to people guessing what you mean. This isn't rocket science.

Comment: in the comment above i did use verbatim and linked where it was said. im not sure how else i can phrase the question but here goes. The article https://www.sma-sunny.com/en/bad-power-factor-a-reason-to-oversize-your-inverter/ states that "SMA inverters can generate reactive power without using any active power." My question is; can a battery inverter also generate reactive power like the string inverter? p.s. thank you for helping

Answer (score 1):

First, Power Factor (and its correction) does not relate to the batteries themselves in any way. Power Factor has meaning in AC circuits and the batteries are DC devices.

The batteries are never discharged by the charger. They are discharged by the equipment they power.

One of the problems discussed in the paper is that the power factor of the charger may depend on the charger's load. It is implied that the charger's load depends on the battery "state of charge" (or discharge depth).

That's where the power factor and the discharge are related (not much, in fact).

p.s.

a traditional, heavy, iron-transformer-based charger looks like this:
AC grid voltage => Transformer => AC battery voltage => rectifier => DC battery voltage => battery

The source of the reactive energy (and low PF) is the transformer and/or regulating circuit that may be at any of the above stages.

a modern, inverter-based charger looks like this:

AC grid voltage => rectifier => DC grid voltage => PFC => DC above-grid voltage => high-frequency inverter => some AC => small transformer => AC battery voltage => rectifier => DC battery voltage => battery

Here, the main PF offender is the first rectifier. The PFC may or may not be present and it may or may not be equally efficient at all possible power levels.

Comment: When you mention "charger's load" are you talking about when the battery is being charged, or when it is discharging?

so if a site has a bad PF, i cannot charge my battery to increase the PF? (i know charging the battery is a dc load and will inherently increase the PF but is it possible to charge the battery with reactive power to further increase the PF?)

Comment: The reason i say this is that i believe string inverters from a pv panel can "generate reactive power"  (https://www.sma-sunny.com/en/bad-power-factor-a-reason-to-oversize-your-inverter/) when the solar panels are producing and was wondering if battery inverters can do the same

Comment: When the battery is being discharged, the charger does nothing. Well, there is a marginal case when both the charger and the load are connected to the battery and the load draws more power than the charger can supply. In this case, the charger operates at maximum power and the battery supplies the rest, gradually depleting.

Comment: String solar inverters: well, they (as a power source) can have some less than ideal PFC. One can connect a solar inverter to a battery in order to deplete the battery, returning the power to the grid. Pretty much an exotic use (with some exceptions). This use case is unrelated to the paper (as far as I can read). P.S. I think you just mix two unrelated concepts - a "grid tied inverter" (used in solar installations) and "Inverter-based battery charger". The technology inside is rather similar, but the devices are pretty much distinct and one cannot be used instead of another.

Comment: "Batteries are never discharged by the inverter" is not *technically* true; the inverter does require some power to operate, so the batteries will run down if the inverter is on, even if there's no load on it.

Comment: @Hearth "by the charger" I wrote. Well, some chargers have significant drain when not plugged in AC.

Answer (score 0):

"Can", yes.

Whether any particular inverter *does*, depends on its design.

A trivial example is the (capacitive) reactive power drawn by the output EMI filter of a connected, but not generating, inverter.

Whether that reactive power is corrected by the inverter while operating, or it's set for any particular phase at any particular operating condition, depends wholly on the controller design.

Reactive power has no bearing on the battery / DC side, other than a potential impact on efficiency.